# xamarin for visual studio 2013

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013

I want to install Xamarin.VS 4.2.0.719 for Visual studio 2013 ultimate.
Tried looking for older releases of Xamarin at https://releases.xamarin.com/category/visual-studio-tools-for-xamarin/page/10/
but couldn't find any installable link.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The machine I have been allocated is having visual studio 2013 ultimate installed. Now I am trying to install Xamarin (Version 4.2.0.719)for visual studio.
I tried searching for the older releases at releases.xamarin.com but over there I just get release notes.
I need the downloadable link to get Xamarin on my machine. Moreover where can I get Xamarin Installer 3.6.0.0